# Convertir un proyecto de consola en servicio de windows

Tags: servicio, .net-core

Tengo un proyecto de consola en c# .NetCore y quiero instalarlo como servicio de windows.

Lo instale de esta manera:

installutil -i "%documentos%\Proyectos\Pro1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\pp1.exe

Y me tira el siguiente error:

System.BadImageFormatException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'file:///C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Proyectos\Pro1\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\pp1.exe' ni una de sus dependencias. Se esperaba que el módulo tuviera un manifiesto de ensamblado..

Qué puede estar pasando? Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Desde ya, muchas gracias.
Raulus.

Comment: Ahí logré instalarlo con el siguiente comando:

sc create "Servicio" binpath="<ruta del servicio>"

pero no puedo ejecutarlo. Me sale este error:

Error 1053: El servicio no respondió a tiempo a la solicitud de inicio o de control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo instalé con el comando:

sc create "Servicio" binpath=""

El error salía por un problema que tenía en el código. Lo ví por el visor de eventos.